# Replace all the characters of "+" with empty character in string java

Tags: java

I have a string

```
String myString = "Hello+World+How are you";
```

How to replace all `"+"` in `myString` with `empty character`

---

**I tried with**: `myString.replaceAll("+"," ");`

**What I am trying to find**: Regular expression for `+` so I can replace all occurrences

**Output I am trying to achieve:** `Hello World How are you`

Comment: Use `replace` instead or `replaceAll`

Comment: Otherwise you'll need to escape special characters: `myString.replaceAll("\\+", "")`

Comment: It sounds a bit like URL decoding? [`URLDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use [`Pattern.quote(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)

```
String myString = "Hello+World+How are you";
String replaced = myString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("+"), " ");
```

I think it is less error-prone if you (or someone else) need to modify the regexp later.

Answer (score 2):

try with like this

```
myString.replace("+"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\\` with any special charachter in java,so your code will be like this to replace `+` with whitespace:

`myString.replaceAll("\\+"," ");`

Explanation: `\` this is used to escape special characters,and this `\` itself is a special character,that is why we have to use '\\'.